# What is `Init for Update` thread state in mariadb?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Our production server gets stuck on `Init for update` state whenever we start a query like

```
update 
    <some_big_table> 
set 
    <primary_key> = <some_sequence>.nextval 
order by 
    <some_indexed_field>
```

While this the query is stuck are this state, all other queries get stuck at commit or writing to binlog state.

I couldn't find any relevant documentation for the same either.

Comment: You should never rewrite your primary key. I assume your primary key is auto_increment and you want to remove some gaps or something? Use a separate column if you want a clean sequential numbering. A PK's single purpose is to uniquely identify a row. And it determines in which order rows are stored on disk. If you rewrite the PK, you're forcing MySQL to rewrite the table, which is an expensive operation.

Comment: That i understand due to btree index organisation of innodb, however what's causing this and is this a bug? How can one select query block commits of all other ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has to change every row in the table.  So it effectively locks the entire table.  And it takes a long time.

Hence, it blocks other queries touching the table for any purpose.

As for the "state" -- It is like most states, it does not mean much.  And is possibly misleading.  (I would expect it to be finished with "init" and "performing" the update.)